# JAX-RS REST asynchronous

Tags: java, rest, asynchronous, jax-rs

When using asynchronous operations in Jax-rs there are two possibilities of using:

1) Server Asynchronous Response Processing;

2) AsyncInvoker Client API;

Which of those should I use? Maybe should I use both of them?

Comment: First is for the server side, second is for the client side

Comment: Ok, it is possible for example to configure asynchronous operations only server side while client may know nothing about asynchronous? And vice-verca.

Comment: Hi @rozero , what is the practical use case of using async REST. I was going to post a question on Stack Overflow saw your post.